# c# create a virtual port using VSPE

Tags: c#, api, serial-port

I'm trying to create a virtual port using a VSPE api .

I try to run the demo code , I get no errors - but it doesn't create me the port .

any idea why?

this is the api guide :
http://grzelewski.net/docs/VSPE/CCOMinterface.html

and this is the code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VSPELib;

namespace VSPE_API_Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private VSPEApiClass vspe;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vspe = new VSPEApiClass();
            int result;
            string activationKey = "SRBGMZSYPuIHWILsmLjF5CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPRJEEYxlJg + 4gdYguyYuMXkIPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9CDyBL3GQYD0IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9JyUaC2ZWE1DZV2 + wYWlRm7FFYrW3MDbZg8MkQsOQ8r1IPIEvcZBgPQg8gS9xkGA9LzrhjimHDiMlKqr6pSiw9CDl9n + 0bAgFr2ho7nXjCoTMHYzt4tsbEkJGNktLGVG42SZ63UbmIUNcKmfhSzXldVCLhfvZv3StR9c / vkYG471Nh62eC1qIYuBUvm + a3BK8iR0POD8w5ovtuYr0T8aQP3eh4b8lUwnPHG9NRJxerttq / +/ zX7c++9LDSQym3ThbWesK + A + X / vNw9qDgYt1dsJxDEEytsCRiT7bTiV5Djh1RlpIwETXWA089hiE9OYd7GpjKLq5dQOqSVcA3Fg1Wfdbqn / yn8q0 / AIDOd0iZlbVeLY68zKh1Di4gGEoa1kR8EOBp2mxeaFrfwUm3DsJ5Pc04f7aEw9XljfBUwl / bAs3LVH5HRii8lXZvUVvnnfpcQ == 1F250CF0960AE1C09E9450C816DE1232"; // <-----  PUT ACTIVATION KEY HERE
                                       // display VSPE API info
            label1.Text = vspe.vspe_getVersionInformation();
            // activate VSPE API
            result = vspe.vspe_activate(activationKey);
            // initialize API
            result = vspe.vspe_initialize();


            label2.Text = "Done!";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Info_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // get devices count
            int count = vspe.vspe_getDevicesCount();
            string result = "Devices count: " + count.ToString() + "\n";
            // enumerate devices
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
            {
                // get device ID
                int deviceId = vspe.vspe_getDeviceIdByIdx(i);
                string name, initString;
                int ok, used;
                vspe.vspe_getDeviceInfo(deviceId, out name, out initString, out ok, out used);
                result += name + " (" + initString + ") OK=" + ok.ToString() + "\n";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(result);

        }

        private void CreateDevice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result;
            // Stop emulation
            result = vspe.vspe_stopEmulation();
            // Deatroy all devices
            result = vspe.vspe_destroyAllDevices();
            // Add Connector (COM9, no baud rate emulation)
            result = vspe.vspe_createDevice("Connector", "9;0");
            // Start emulation
            result = vspe.vspe_startEmulation();
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the "Info" button - I get
Devices count: 0

- if you have another why to create a virtual port - I will be glad to hear and do it

Thanks ,

Comment: Have you created a device first? If yes, then use debugger to check the ID of the device (value that `VSPEApiClass.vspe_createDevice()` returns) and explicitly request information by that ID.

Comment: i will give it a try - Thanks!